# Como faço para trocar o texto no unity3d com um script que não posso retirar?

Tags: c#, unity3d, edittext

Estou com um problema no `unity3d` e não sei como resolver.

Eu tenho um determinado script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CharacterSelector : MonoBehaviour

{
    [SerializeField]

    private Text bio1 = null;
    private Text data2 = null;
    private Text name = null;
    private Text subname = null;
    private GameObject[] characterList;
    private int index;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterList = new GameObject[transform.childCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            characterList[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            foreach (GameObject f in characterList)
            {
                f.SetActive(false);
                if (characterList[0])
                    characterList[0].SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ToggleLeft()
    {
        //desligar o modelo atual
        characterList[index].SetActive(false);
        index--;
        if (index < 0)
            index = characterList.Length - 1;
        //ligar o modelo atual
        characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ToggleRight()
    {
        //desligar o modelo atual
        characterList[index].SetActive(false);
        index++;
        if (index == characterList.Length)
            index = 0;
        //ligar o modelo atual
        characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void COnfirmButton()
    {
        if (index == 0) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("NeroRoom");             
        }
        if (index == 1) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
        }

    }
    public void ChangeText() 
    {
        if (index == 0) 
        {
            name.text = "Mac Logan";
            subname.text = "O coração valente";
        }
    }
}
```

Esse script está ligado a um gameobject que tem os personagens do game que dependendo de cada um a biografia e especificações vão mudar. Isso pode ser percebido no Public void COnfirmButton.

Então como eu faço para mudar um texto dependendo dos personagens que estiverem aparecendo?

A parte do [SerializeField] até `private Text subname = null`; eu vi em um tutorial mas não deu certo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ja tentas-te activar e desactivar textos ? Ex: utilizar a seguite condicao em script:
Se a personagem `x` estiver activa aparece o texto de `x`, se tiver a personagem `y` activa aparece o texto de `y`, e assim sucessivamente fazendo acorrespondencia de cada personagem a cada texto activando e desactivando textos e Objectos.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que pegar o componente de texto usando

```
Text descricao = GetComponent<Text>()
```

Ou declarar uma variável

```
public Text descricao;
```

E no editor, associar o componente de texto que vai ser mudado pro campo.
Depois é só escrever `descricao.text = "Texto a ser mudado"`.

Agora, pra colocar um texto diferente pra cada personagem, você precisa de um componente no `gameobject` do personagem.

Crie um Script com um nome como "`InfoPersonagem`", e nele declare uma string "descricao" e coloque o texto que você quer.
Depois, é só colocar:

`descricao.text = characterList[index].GetComponent<InfoPersonagem>().descricao`;